# AWS CodeDeploy: In Appspec.yml Move Files That Are More Than 1 Folder Deep

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, aws-code-deploy

In my appspec.yml file I need to deploy files that are more than one level deep. The following example will only get files in the views folder but within views folder there are other folders/files I need.

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /views
    destination: /var/www/views
```

Again this gives me all the files in /views but I need the folders within the /views folder.

I've tried adding another entry after views for the folders but that doesn't work. It'll give the error "No such file or directory".

Comment: I've been working on a work around. In the buildspec I zip the folder and bring that zip over in appspec. In appspec I use the AfterInstall hook to unzip. Some reason this unzip doesn't work? If I run the command manually in the EC2 instance it works. Other hook sh scripts work, just not unzip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The work around: zip application folder into source build then unzip when deploying.

buildspec.yml

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Entered the post_build phase...
      - zip -r site.zip ./*
      - echo Build completed on `date`
artifacts:
  files:
    - appspec.yml
    - site.zip
    - DeployScripts/*
```

appspec.yml

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: site.zip
    destination: /var/www/ecommercepricing
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - location: DeployScripts/UnzipSite.sh
      timeout: 400
```

DeployScripts/UnzipSite.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Starting unzip
apt-get install -y unzip
unzip -o /var/www/ecommercepricing/site -d /var/www/ecommercepricing
echo Finishing unzip
```